# Ubuntu Port 80 from some hosts not reachable

Tags: networking, iptables

I have an ubuntu-server in a LAN. Whenever I try to run a Web-Server like apache2, or any other server like node.js on port 80 it is only reachable for some hosts in the network (the browser is loading for a while and then it shows the browser-specific not found screen [not an apache site not found]). And it seems to change who is able to access it. 
Here is the **iptables -L** output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I don't think it is a problem with apache, since as I said it doesn't work with Node, too.

Do you guys have any idea what else I could check?
This issue has been giving me headache for a while now..

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Thanks & Best,
Marc

Comment: How is it reachable and yet it shows the browser-specific not found screen?

Comment: Which hosts can and cannot reach it - could it be that only hosts in its own subnet can reach it? Can the hosts that can't connect to it, `ping` it? Can the server ping the hosts that can't reach it? If the answers are Yes, No, No, then your server probably has a problem in its routing table. In particular, its gateway(s) may be configured wrongly.

Comment: All hosts were in the same subnet. The hosts that couldn't connect to it also couldn't ping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an internal policy that somehow blocked port 80 and only allowed 443. Switching to https and it worked fine. I have no idea why it worked for some hosts though.